# How to Integrate Fire TV Remote Control Functionality in a Flutter App?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm developing an application using Flutter for Amazon Fire TV, and I'm facing challenges in handling the remote control inputs. My app needs to respond to key events from the Fire TV remote, but I'm not sure how to implement this. Is there any plugin or library specifically designed for this purpose in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

to get remote key acces

```
Shortcuts(
  shortcuts: <LogicalKeySet, Intent>{
    LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.select): const ActivateIntent(),
  },)
```